# How should I architect JasperReports with a PHP front+backend system

Tags: java, php, architecture, jasper-reports

Our system is written completely in PHP.
For various business reasons (which are a given) I need to build the reports of the system using [JasperReports](http://jasperforge.org/).
What architecture should I use? Should I put the Jasper as a stand alone server (if possible) and let the php query against it, should I have it generate the reports with a cron, and then let the PHP scoop up the files and send them to the web client/browser...

Answer (score 1):

[JasperServer](http://www.jaspersoft.com/jasperserver) seems to be the best option, having:

> Comprehensive Web Services, Java, and HTTP APIs, as well as support for Web Services from non-Java environments such as .NET (C#), C++, and PHP

Another option is to implement something like that yourself, with only the functionality you need. Make a separate java web-app that generates the reports, using either web-services or REST to communicate with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to keep things simple and "free", then i recommend:

- Build your own small Java webapp.
- Use DynamicJasper to build customized reports.
- Expose a web service from the Java app, and call it from your PHP.
- Java app will reply with a PDF file.

Comment: instead of web service, I assume I can also use a simple iframe, correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the php java extension and compile and generate the report right from php.   Example code and instructions: [here](http://www.rjohnson.id.au/wordpress/2007/10/27/bullet-proof-jasper-reports-and-php/).